# Strange TestNg DataProvider MethodMatcherException

Tags: java-8, mockito, testng, powermockito, testng-dataprovider

The DataProvider returns exactly the number and type of arguments required by the method.

This error is strange because if I substitute change the parameter and argument to use `List<Experiment>` instead of an `Experiment[]` then no exception is raised.

The method is:

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "provideExperimentId")
 public void testDetermineExperimentId(Experiment[] experiments, int experimentId, int expected)
 {
     mockExperimentId(experiments, experimentId)
     assertEquals(fileParser.determineExperimentId(), expected);
 }
```

The `mockExperimentId(Experiment[], int)` method sets up some when-then clauses,
and uses the parameters to customise some return values.

The data provider is:

```
 @DataProvider
 private Object[][] provideExperimentId(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        return new Object[][]{
            {new Experiment[]{mockedExperiment}, 1, 1}
        };
    }
```

For some reason, I get the following mismatch exception, even though the number of arguments and the types are in agreement.

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: testDetermineExperimentId([Parameter{index=0, type=[Lcom.redacted.Experiment;, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=int, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=int, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [([Lcom.redacted.Experiment;) [mockedExperiment],(java.lang.Integer) 1,(java.lang.Integer) 1]

at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:973)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

However, changing the method and DataProvider to use a list raises no exception

```
@Test(dataProvider = "provideExperimentId")
 public void testDetermineExperimentId(List<Experiment> experiments, int experimentId, int expected)
 {
     mockExperimentId(experiments.toArray(new Experiment[0]), experimentId)
     assertEquals(fileParser.determineExperimentId(), expected);
 }
```

The `mockExperimentId(Experiment[], int)` method sets up some when-then clauses,
and uses the parameters to customise some return values

```
 @DataProvider
 private Object[][] provideExperimentId(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        return new Object[][]{
            {Arrays.asList(mockedExperiment), 1, 1}
        };
    }
```

Comment: Really nice question for a newbie. Source code, stack trace, seems like "all we need" is here. I am not an expert into these areas, but I will see if I kind help later today or tomorrow!